# I am getting below error on trying to use cucumber extentreports

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, gherkin, extentreports

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Test name must not be null or empty     at com.aventstack.extentreports.util.Assert.notEmpty(Assert.java:12)    at com.aventstack.extentreports.ExtentTest.\<init\>(ExtentTest.java:96)     at com.aventstack.extentreports.ExtentTest.createNode(ExtentTest.java:153)  at com.aventstack.extentreports.cucumber.adapter.ExtentCucumberAdapter.createScenarioOutline(ExtentCucumberAdapter.java:374)    at com.aventstack.extentreports.cucumber.adapter.ExtentCucumberAdapter.handleScenarioOutline(ExtentCucumberAdapter.java:353)    at com.aventstack.extentreports.cucumber.adapter.ExtentCucumberAdapter.handleTestCaseStarted(ExtentCucumberAdapter.java:162)    at com.aventstack.extentreports.cucumber.adapter.ExtentCucumberAdapter.access$100(ExtentCucumberAdapter.java:63)    at com.aventstack.extentreports.cucumber.adapter.ExtentCucumberAdapter$3.receive(ExtentCucumberAdapter.java:107)    at com.aventstack.extentreports.cucumber.adapter.ExtentCucumberAdapter$3.receive(ExtentCucumberAdapter.java:104)    at io.cucumber.core.eventbus.AbstractEventPublisher.send(AbstractEventPublisher.java:51)    at io.cucumber.core.eventbus.AbstractEventBus.send(AbstractEventBus.java:12)    at io.cucumber.core.runtime.SynchronizedEventBus.send(SynchronizedEventBus.java:47)     at io.cucumber.core.runtime.ThreadLocalRunnerSupplier$LocalEventBus.send(ThreadLocalRunnerSupplier.java:62)     at io.cucumber.core.runner.TestCase.emitTestCaseStarted(TestCase.java:206)  at io.cucumber.core.runner.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:72)   at io.cucumber.core.runner.Runner.runPickle(Runner.java:75)
```

added below dependency in pom.xml file

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
    <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.9</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are certain minor details which when skipped, you get this exception. To solve this follow the below checklist.

1. Check if both the following dependencies are added to your `pom.xml` file.

```xml
    <!-- extent reports -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
      <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
      <version>5.1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>tech.grasshopper</groupId>
      <artifactId>extentreports-cucumber7-adapter</artifactId>
      <version>1.14.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- extent reports -->
```

2. Make sure you configure your `TestRunner` with the plugin.

```java
@CucumberOptions(
    features = "src/test/resources/features",
    glue = "org/example/step/definitions",
    plugin = { "com.aventstack.extentreports.cucumber.adapter.ExtentCucumberAdapter:" }
)
public class TestNGRunner extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests {

    // to enable parallel processing override the method at runtime
    @DataProvider(parallel = true)
    @Override
    public Object[][] scenarios() {
        return super.scenarios();
    }
}
```

3. Make sure all your features files have a valid description after the `Feature` keyword.

```gherkin
# somefeature.feature file

Feature: Place the order for the product
```

4. Check all your feature files to see if you've missed out a description for any scenario. If yes, you need to populate it.

```gherkin
# somefeature.feature file

Feature: ...

  Scenario Outline: user should be able to place order and checkout items
```

So your final feature file should look similar to the below file with both step 2 and 3 completed.

```gherkin
# somefeature.feature file

Feature: Place the order for the product

  Scenario Outline: user should be able to place order and checkout items
    Given ...
    When ...
    And ...
    Then ...
    And ...
    Examples:
      | Name |
      | Tom  |
      | Cau  |
```

That's it. You should now be able to run the tests without any exception.